# Python - remove leading zeros from IP addresses

Tags: python, regex, ip-address

I am trying to remove leading zeros from IP addresses but it's not working

```
import re

def remove_zeros_from_ip(ip_add):
  string = re.sub('(?!(\.0\.))(\.[0]{1,2})', '.', ip_add)  
  return string

ip = '10.0.01.10'
print(remove_zeros_from_ip(ip))

ip1 = '10.00.002.20'
print(remove_zeros_from_ip(ip1))
```

but getting this-

```
10.0.1.10
10..2.20
```

How to get?-

```
10.0.1.10
10.0.2.20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the zeros that are preceded by a `.` or `^` (start of line) and followed by anything other than a `.` with what preceded it (`.` or start of line):

```
import re

def remove_zeros_from_ip(ip_adr):
  return re.sub('(^|\.)0+(?=[^.])', r'\1', ip_adr)
```

Test:

```
print(remove_zeros_from_ip('10.0.01.10'))

print(remove_zeros_from_ip('10.00.002.20'))

print(remove_zeros_from_ip('0010.00.02.0020'))
```

Output:

```
10.0.1.10
10.0.2.20
10.0.2.20
```

A non-regex solution would be to split the strings by a `.` and use `str.rstrip` to remove the leading zeros, then, use `str.join` to reconstruct the string:

```
def remove_zeros_from_ip(ip_adr): 
  return '.'.join(p.lstrip('0') or '0' for p in ip_adr.split('.'))
```

Comment: The code seems to work, but your description is wrong - you don't want to remove zeros that are followed by anything other than a `.`. For example, `10.0.102.20`. But your code seems to handle it properly.

Comment: @scatter Right, it should be _preceded by a `.` and followed by anything other than a `.`_.

Answer (score 4):

You can split the IP octets and then convert Octets in string to int, and then back to str.

```
>>> ip='10.00.01.10'
>>> '.'.join([str(int(x)) for x in ip.split('.')])
'10.0.1.10'
```

Comment: Came to say this. Integers already don't have leading zeroes, so converting parts into integers and back is the easiest option if that's all one has to do!

Answer (score 0):

If the only data is an ip, you could use a word boundary `\b`, match 1+ zeroes and use a capturing group to match 1+ digits and use that group in the replacement.

```
\b0+(\d+)
```

Replace with

```
r'\1'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRxAe2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fSRXaY)

For example

```
import re

def remove_zeros_from_ip(ip_add):
  string = re.sub(r'\b0+(\d+)', r'\1', ip_add)  
  return string

ip = '10.0.01.10'
print(remove_zeros_from_ip(ip))

ip1 = '10.00.002.20'
print(remove_zeros_from_ip(ip1))
```

Output

```
10.0.1.10
10.0.2.20
```

Comment: 10.0.102.20 gives 10.0.12.20.  This is the correct format - re.sub('\.0+(\d+)', r'.\1', ip_add)

Comment: @Arif You are right, I forgot the word boundary `\b`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
0*(\d+)
```

In English: greedily find zeros until we encounter any other digit sequence. Store the digit sequence in `\1`

https://regex101.com/r/sEdwMK/1

Comment: The replacement works but I think there will be more replacements than necessary as the pattern also matches parts that don't need replacement.